# Geolocation doesn't work even on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

I am struggling with geolocation on simulator, but recently, I have tested it directly on device (iPhone) but the same issue remains, here is what I got when my app finish launching and the code of geolocation suppose to give me my location on the map (remember the picture above is for my app on iPhone and not with the simulator) :

[image]

so for my code, my app actually have a lot of views, but concerning this function, I have worked on the appdelegate(.m and .h) and the view concerning of showing the location on the map (PositionActuelleViewController).

appdelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    sleep(3);




    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.locationManager=[[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];

    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.locationManager.delegate=self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter=100;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }


        // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

and in the same file after the dealloc method :

```
     #pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods


    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation    {

        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
        span.longitudeDelta=0.2;


        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.span=span;
        region.center=newLocation.coordinate;
        [viewCont.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

        viewCont.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
        viewCont.latitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        viewCont.longitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

}
```

my PositionActuelleViewController.m file :

```
#import "PositionActuelleViewController.h"
@implementation PositionActuelleViewController

@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;

-(IBAction)goBackToMenu {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)goToRechercherView;
{
    rechercherViewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self  presentModalViewController:rechercherViewController animated:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [mapView release];
    [latitude release];
    [longitude release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I hope you didn't forget to attach `mapView` in IB?

Comment: i did, if it's not attached it wouldn't be implemented and it would quit the app when the view is load :)

Comment: ok, i have just check it in IB and it's attached to my file's owner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the delegate method `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` ever get called? Maybe if you uncomment `self.locationManager.distanceFilter=100;` it will work because according to docs, `distanceFilter` property defines the minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move laterally before an update event is generated.

Comment: Hi kakoSquid, i have uncommented the self.locationManager.distanceFilter=100; statement and try to build so my map is shown, i waited a while hoping it work but the app quited and i find my self out :( does that mean this may be work when i move this build with this modification on iPhone ?? thx

Comment: I think that could be a cause to your problems... Plus do uncomment sleep(3), that could cause unstable behaviour

Comment: the sleep(3) is for my splashscreen.

Comment: By the way, the locationManager method is in the appdelegate.m, should i call it in the - (void)viewDidLoad of the view where the map suppose to be shown ??

Comment: It really doesn't matter which class is the delegate for your CLLocationManager, as long as it conforms to CLLocationManagerDelegate and implements the delegate methods. Also check if the location services are enabled :)